# background-color and content in different positions

Tags: html, css, background-color

I have a div that contains an image and some text, and has a background-color. However, when it renders on chrome and firefox, the background-color is out of position and the div content is in the correct position, but it works fine in IE8, I just can't fathom what might be causing this, it's a royal pain there I tell u...

```
<div style="width:800px;margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;background-color:yellow;"> 
<div style="height:30px;">
</div>
<div style="width:400px;height:150px;">
<div style="float:left;padding:none;padding-top:40px;padding-left:30px;">
<img src="warning.jpg" style="float:left;"/>
</div>

<div style="width:300px;float:left;padding-left:10px;padding-right:10px;">
<h6 style="font-family:Palatino Linotype;font-size:12px;">
Do not give your personal information to anyone you have not met over the internet or     phone, or send money to anyone without verifying what you are paying for. lokalboard.com will not be responsible for any loss on third party transactions made between its users.
</h6>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: If I might add, there is a div before this div block, which is floating to the left of a main div, and I just noticed that if I remove the float left property of that div, the background-color falls right in place...

Comment: Mate you should format your code and ask a question more accurate. I have no idea what you are talking about...

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Kolyunya/EZhVc/ what do you want to achieve?

Comment: I can't imagine what you mean by `background-color` falling out of place myself.

Comment: Your code has a pretty large number of tags, especially divs, in relation to the actual content you need to display. Maybe you've stripped some of the content to ask your question. In any case, I cleaned that up because I was having problems thinking about it. http://jsfiddle.net/Rfc8Q/

Comment: Thanks guys, but i found that if I put a clear : left in the main div container containing the image and text, it renders how it's supposed to bcos the main div before it is floating to the left, so it has to have a clear property to function properly. However, it's very strange if you see the misplacement of the background-color occur, bcos the content of the div is in the right position but the background is somewhere far off. Anyways, the moral of this lesson is to always use clear : float property after floating some elements. Thanks for your input in any case.